# Возможно, чтоб not null LiveData возвращала null значение?

Tags: android, kotlin, livedata

Есть `LiveData` на котороую подписывается `View` вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В аналитике вижу отчет об краше в котором говориться

```
Location: MyFile.kt line 116 in MyFragment$setupObservers$2.invoke
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Message: it must not be null
```

Функция `enableContinueButton(state: Boolean)` не принимает, `null` значения, так же как `LiveData` не возвращает `null`

```
...
protected val _fieldsValidated = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val fieldsValidated: LiveData<Boolean> =  _fieldsValidated
...
```

Но судя по ошибке `LiveData` все же возвращает `null` в 116й строке и случается краш.

Вопрос: как это возможно?

Comment: А что вот тут: `_fieldsValidated`? И в каком порядке оно инициализируется и откуда и как получает данные?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил в вопрос строчку насчет `_fieldsValidated`, то есть эти два поля обьявлены в начале класса и инициализируются в таком же порядке. Если я правильно понял насчет "от куда получает данные", то данные обновляются стандартно через `.value = ...`. Не понятно как `null` даже теоритически может быть возвращен в `.observalbe` если он не `nullable`...

Comment: Ну, судя по ошибке, видимо, где-то в `_fieldsValidated.value = ...` вместо многоточия `null` прилетает. В теории такое возможно. Например да, порядок инициализации членов класса может быть причиной. Например, если объявить notNull член класса типа так: `val test: String = "test"` и поместить его после `init` блока, в котором к нему обращение идёт `init { println(test) }` то будет NPE, т.к. `test` ещё не инициализирован. Мне думается, что стоит в эту сторону копать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, я тоже думал об этом, но проверил всю локигу (там не так много) все вроде как правильно, и сбиват тот факт, что отчет показывает строку 116... то есть как будто значение получает в observable как `null` (хотя not null LiveData не может нести null). Я имеею ввиду, если б LiveDate кто то обновлял как `null` то краш был бы там, а не в `observalbe`.

Comment: `MutableLiveData` написан в Java, там `null` легко образуется :) https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/lifecycle/lifecycle-livedata-core/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.java

Comment: Поэтому и креш только в момент попадания этого `null` в Котлин `observable`.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja с одной стороны это звучит не плохо, но я бы не ожидал тогда креш в observable если бы `null` был бы присвоен `not-null` LiveData я бы ожидал креш как раз в строке где его присваивают (`.value = null`), верно?

Comment: @Sirop4ik в новых версиях уже хотя бы подсвечивает комплиятор, что сетать null в not-null LD опасно. но дальше чем просто "не делай так", ничего не заходит(( сам с этим борюсь вот таким способом `var <T>MutableLiveData<T>.mValue: T
    @Deprecated("unsafe method. use classic Value")
    get() = value!!
    set(newValue) {
        this.value = newValue
    }`

Comment: @Wlad, в исходнике `MutableLiveData` 2 конструктора, 2 метода и все четверо тупо делегируют вызов предку. Разве нельзя сделать тоже самое на котлине и использовать свой класс вместо библиотечного? А то `@Deprecated("unsafe method...` как-то некрасиво

Comment: @woesss конечно можно. даже тупое копирование исходника Java в Котлин решает проблему ТСа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблема заключается в том, что `MutalbeLiveData` написана на джаве как результат получается, что даже `not-null LiveData` все равно очень хорошо принимает `null` значения и когда обзервер подпишиться на нее то неожиданно `null` будет возвращен в `not-null LiveData`.

**Как решить проблему?** Есть два возможных способа, первый в котором `null` просто не будет прилитать в обзервер и второй где LiveData будет крашиться на моменте где значение присваивается (`.value = null`), а не в обзервере, то есть можно будет легче понять от куда прилетает `null`

**Первое решение:**

```
class NonNullMediatorLiveData<T> : MediatorLiveData<T>()

fun <T> NonNullMediatorLiveData<T>.observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: (t: T) -> Unit) {
    this.observe(owner, Observer {
        it?.let(observer)
    })
}

fun <T> LiveData<T>.nonNull(): NonNullMediatorLiveData<T> {
    val mediator: NonNullMediatorLiveData<T> = NonNullMediatorLiveData()
    mediator.addSource(this) { it?.let { mediator.value = it } }
    return mediator
}
```

использование:

```
...
myLiveData.nonNull().observe(...) { ... }
...
```

**Второе решение:**

```
class NonnullableMutableLiveData<T: Any>: MutableLiveData<T>() {
    override fun postValue(value: T) = super.postValue(value)
    override fun setValue(value: T) = super.setValue(value)
}
```

Использование:

```
...
val myLiveData: NonnullableMutableLiveData....
...
```

Ну и естественно в зависимости от ситуации испозовать одно или другое.